# Python: Run a GUI that is tracking real time

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

How do I import dynamic time onto tkinter? The import date.time function will only import the data from that specific time it is ran. I want the code to run once but still be collecting time data like a loop.

Comment: Do you want to emulate a clock?

Comment: use `root.after(time, function)` to run "function" after "time" milliseconds. Inside this function you run `after` again to get loop which doesn't block GUI. Inside this function you can get current time `date.time` and use it. Examples which use `after` to display current time in Label in tkinter: [furas/python-examples/tkinter/timer-using-after](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread that uploads a variable with the actual time.

```
def This_Thread():

    def Start_Acq():
        Eth_BG = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

        def Configure(sc):

            # do your stuff, for example:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y; %H:%M:%S")

            DSP_BG.enter(Insert_Here_Your_Rate, Insert_Here_Your_Priority, Configure, (DSP_BG,))
            DSP_BG.run()

    Ethernet_thread = threading.Thread(target=Start_Acq)
    Ethernet_thread.start()
```